# opencv c++で輪郭を四角で囲んだ後の四角の座標を出力したいです

Tags: c++, opencv

URLのプログラムと同じです。
輪郭を長方形で囲むところまでは出来ています!
そこから座標をだしたいのですがなかなか上手くいきません。
よろしくお願いいたします。    
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  /// Create Window
  char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

  createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat threshold_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using Threshold
  threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
  vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
  vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
       boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
       minEnclosingCircle( (Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
     }


  /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
       rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
       circle( drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0 );
     }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
}
```

Comment: 対象が「点」でなく「長方形=平面」であるなら、求めたい座標は「中心」なのか「四隅のいずれか」などを考える必要がありそうです。

Comment: rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );で長方形の左上と右上の座標が出てる様なのでとりあえずはその2点を表示できたらなと考えています！

Answer (score 1):

cygwin64 で次のようにコンパイル・実行できたので同じようにすればなんとかなりそう。

```
$ cat piyo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main() {
  cv::Rect r;
  r.x = 10;
  r.y = 20;
  r.width = 30;
  r.height = 40;
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

$ g++ piyo.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
$ ./a.exe
[30 x 40 from (10, 20)]
$
```

`boundRect[i]` を同じように表示すればイケるはず。

---

質問文中の「輪郭」計算結果は `boundRect` という変数に格納されています（ブツが複数個ある場合のために `std::vector<cv::Rect>` となっています）。なので計算結果を取得した後、破棄される前であれば表示させることができます。どこで輪郭計算をしているか、どこで破棄されるか、はわかりますか？

```
rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
cout << boundRect[i] << endl; // この行をここに追加
```

のように `for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )` 中に書き加えるといいでしょう。これだと標準出力に出力されていますが、標準出力がどこになっているかは要注意っす（コンソール画面かもしれないしデバッガかもしれないので確認作業は慎重に） GUI 画面上に吹き出しみたいな形で表示したいならそれなりの仕様設計＋実装が必要です。

Comment: プログラミング初心者で初歩的な質問になってしまうかもしれません。そのままのプログラムをコピペすれば当然デバックの実行をすると、[30 x 40 from (10, 20)]が永遠に表示されてしまいます。それは当然なのですが、実際の座標の得方が分からないです

Comment: できました！大変わかりやすい説明でとても助かりました！

Comment: すみません加えて質問よいでしょうか？tl,brで左上と右下のｘｙ座標がでています。ただｔｌのｘとｙを別々で扱いたい場合どうしたらよいでしょうか？具体的には、その長方形の一番左のｘ座標と一番右のｘ座標を足したり引いたりしたいです

Comment: 他の Q&A サイトでもそうですが、特に stackoverflow では一問一答が好まれます。 SO では「コメント」は目立たない仕様なのでコメントに質問を書いても閲覧者が少なく答えを得られる機会が減ってしまいます。新規質問は新規発言でぜひどうぞー。ちなみに、この発言質疑応答上のチェックマークをクリックして「役に立った」マークをつけてくれるとお互いハッピーになれますよ。

Comment: 不慣れなのでとても参考になりました！役に立ったも押しましたがどうやら信用度？が低くて表示はされなかったです！https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52451/opencv-c-描いた長方形の重心と長方形の一番左の%ef%bd%98座標一番右の%ef%bd%99座標をだしたい　で再度質問させて頂いたので時間ございましたら答えて頂けると幸いです