# opencv c++　描いた長方形の重心と長方形の一番左のｘ座標一番右のｙ座標をだしたい

Tags: c++, opencv

```
rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
```

で、長方形の左上右下の座標はだせているのですが、それを利用しての重心の出し方がよくわからないです。brにｘ座標とｙ座標２つのデータ。同様にｔｌに２つのデータが入っています。
brのx座標だけ、tlのx座標だけをそれぞれx1やx2などとして出せないでしょうか？

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  /// Create Window
  char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

  createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat threshold_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using Threshold
  threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
  vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
  vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
       boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
       minEnclosingCircle( (Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
     }


  /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
       rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
       circle( drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0 );
     }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

玉掛け試験受ける予定のオイラとしては「重心」の厳密定義が欲しいところですが、まあ普通には、一様な長方形の重心は対角線の交点ですし、それは単に中心ですよね。

http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn/cpp/basic_structures.html
を見るに `Rect_` は、左上座標 `(x, y)` と大きさ `width, height` をメンバに持つクラステンプレートです。今使っている `Rect` (アンダースコアがないもの）は `typedef Rect_<int> Rect;` なので `int` で実体化したものであることがわかります。

ということで `Rect r;` があるとき、その中心座標（重心）は `Point p(r.x+r.width/2, r.y+r.height/2);` で良さそうですが、これが期待された答えでしょうか？　提示コードに応用するために具体的にどう書けばよいかはあえて示しません。

---

左上座標 `(x, y)` と大きさ `width, height` があれば、右上座標が `(x+width, y)` で左下座標が `(x, y+height)` であることは自明なような気がします（何か悩ましいですか？）すでに用意されている `Rect_::tl()` であるとか `Rect_::br()` (それぞれ Top Left, Bottom Right でしょう) を使わなければならない理由はないですよね。んで [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) で座標は `cv::Point_` クラステンプレートで表記するわけで、整数系でよければ

```
Point left_bottom(x, y+height);
```

と書くであろう、ことは簡単に想像できますよね。

`Rect r;` があるとき 左下は `Point lb1(r.x, r.y+r.height);` でしょうし
`Rect s;` があるとき 左下は `Point lb2(s.x, s.y+s.height);` でしょうし
`Rect t;` があるとき 左下は `Point lb3(t.x, t.y+t.height);` でしょうし
となれば `Rect` である `boundRect[i]` があるとき左下は・・・以下略

右上も重心も同じことなんぢゃないですか？ そのくらいの応用は（基本中の基本であって応用ではないですけど）当然できるはず。

まだわからなかったらコメントでなくて質問文の編集をお願いします。

Comment: 思ったのですが重心だけなら、長方形以外にも円も描かれているのでcout <<center[i].x << endl;とかでｘ座標やｙ座標だしても大丈夫なのでしょうか？